# Can i pair Max reading with Date of that Max reading?

Tags: excel

I have a list of numbers for every day of the month. I've used the MAX function to get the highest reading of the month, but my question is, Can I also have the date of the highest reading automatically filled?

Example

1/1/2019  **89**

1/2/2019  **15**

1/3/2019  **100**

---

**MAX       100 1/3/2019**

Comment: See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas about what kind of questions can be made and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

In **C2** enter:

```
=MAX(B:B)
```

and in **D2** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C2,B:B,0))
```

[image]